# Netbeans build configurations

Tags: web-services, netbeans, build

Is it possible to create multiple build configurations/profiles in Netbeans similar to what you can do in Visual Studio?

I am trying to provide different configurations depending on if I'm building for debugging or deployment.

The main thing I really want is to be able to use test web service references when debugging and production web service references when deploying into production.

Is there a way to do this or does anyone have any tips or trick on how they go about similar task?

Answer (score 1):

You sure can.  If you have a Java project (and as long as it was created with Netbeans, this won't work for a free-form project), here are the steps:

1.) Right-click the project->Properties
2.) Navigate to the "Run" properties
3.) Where it says "Configuration" and there is a drop-down box, to the right of that is are buttons "New" and "Delete".  Using these, it is possible to create different contexts from which you can run your application.

If you're using C/C++, the process is similar:

1.) Right-click the project->Properties
2.) Click on the "Manage Configurations"

From there you can create all of the configurations (much like VS) that you would like.  Use can use the other property pages to set your compiler flags, etc...

Hope this helps!